# Resize array and fill with interpolation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

This should be similar to image resealing, suppose having this vector,

```
x = np.array([10,50,40,20])
```

I need to scale it up to size 10, and fill the missing values using interpolation.

Any `numpy` or `scipy` function that does this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way is using [`scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom.html). This will be `zooming` using [spline interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation). In order to use it you need to provide a zooming factor which in this case, given that you want an array of size `10`, it should be `10/len(x)`:

```
from scipy.ndimage import interpolation

x = np.array([10,50,40,20])
i = 10
z = i / len(x)
# 2.5

x_int = interpolation.zoom(x,z)
```

---

**Output**

```
array([10, 18, 35, 50, 54, 49, 40, 30, 23, 20])
```

Comment: Very nice! 
Thanks a lot.